# How do I beat the Fast League?

Tags: magikarp-jump

I'm at the fast league, but I have to beat a guy who has 1000 JP, which might take me 30 generations.

What's the fastest way to beat him?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact details of how many more generations you need to beat the fast league, but I do know until very late in the game it only takes 1/2 extra generations from starting a league, to beating it. The JP scaling spikes quite heavily and soon 1000 JP will seem like a tiny amount. Give it at a couple of generations and I'm confident you'll be able to be the fast league.